# TACUC - The ATaco ChatExchange Userscript Collection

Tags: script, chat, tampermonkey

A collection of Userscripts focused around Stack Exchange's chat.

To install these, you need [TamperMonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/), although GreaseMonkey apparently works.

[GitHub](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/TacosUserscripts)

---

## Auto Chat Jax

This userscript simply implements MathJax across chatrooms automatically, in almost the exact same way as the Bookmarklet. Just convenience.

[image: img]

[<kbd>install / update</kbd>](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/TacosUserscripts/raw/master/autochatjax.user.js) | [<kbd>view source</kbd>](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/TacosUserscripts/blob/master/autochatjax.user.js)

---

## Google Prettify

This takes Codeblocks, both inline and multiline, and takes guesses at what language code they are, and runs it through Google's Prettifier. Syntax Highlighting for chat!

[image: img]

[<kbd>install / update</kbd>](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/TacosUserscripts/raw/master/autogoogleprettychat.user.js) | [<kbd>view source</kbd>](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/TacosUserscripts/blob/master/autogoogleprettychat.user.js)

---

## Caret Reply

A very simple userscript, allows you to reply to previous messages by starting them with any amount of `^`s. The more, the further back it goes.
^ refers to the last message, ^^ refers to the one before that and so on. It saves which message when you start typing, so that you won't get ninja'd.

[<kbd>install / update</kbd>](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/TacosUserscripts/raw/master/caretreply.user.js) | [<kbd>view source</kbd>](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/TacosUserscripts/blob/master/caretreply.user.js)

---

## Chat Commands

Adds commands to autofill some text to chat.
The commands are:

- shrug: "¯\_(ツ)_/¯"
- tableflip: "(ノ°Д°）ノ︵ ┻━┻"
- o_o: "ಠ_ಠ"
- disapprove: "ಠ_ಠ"
- like: "(•◡•)/"
- unflip: "┬─┬ ノ( ゜-゜ノ)"
- donger: "༼ つ ◕_◕ ༽つ"
- why: "ლ(ಠ益ಠლ)"
- cool: "(▀̿Ĺ̯▀̿ ̿)"
- lenny: "( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)"
- $mathjax$: An SVG image based on the entered mathjax. `mathjax` can be any text.
- $$mathjax$: Like the above, but for not-inline mathjax.

Commands are executed by `/command`, and can be run in-line. Pretty much the only useful commands are the MathJax ones, in my personal opinion.

[<kbd>install / update</kbd>](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/TacosUserscripts/raw/master/chatcommands.user.js) | [<kbd>view source</kbd>](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/TacosUserscripts/blob/master/chatcommands.user.js)

---

## Chat Preview

Adds a box which shows, formatted, what you're about to say in chat. Supports my other Userscripts here (Especially Caret Reply) and has some light oneboxing support.

[image: img]

[<kbd>install / update</kbd>](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/TacosUserscripts/raw/master/sechatpreview.user.js) | [<kbd>view source</kbd>](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/TacosUserscripts/blob/master/sechatpreview.user.js)

---

## Strawpoll Onebox

Makes it so `strawpoll.me` links onebox. They refresh automatically, and are just kind of nice to have. Doesn't support `strawpoll.com`.

[<kbd>install / update</kbd>](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/TacosUserscripts/raw/master/strawpollbox.user.js) | [<kbd>view source</kbd>](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/TacosUserscripts/blob/master/strawpollbox.user.js)